# Capitalize the element of list when unpacking

Tags: python-3.8

I'm unable to capitalize the first letter of the list.

```
let = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

count = 5

for x in range(5):
    print(*let[0:count])
    count -= 1
```

So on this example don't know how to make 'a' printed as 'A'.

Comment: If you are modifying the the array, let, you might as well do it outside the loop.  Also, see my answer below on how to eliminate the count variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make change to the print method but you can change your list to make the first element capitalized :
`let[0] = let[0].upper()`.

If for some reason you can't modifiy the initial list make a copy `let2=let` and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it this way:

```
 let = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']      
 for i in range(5, 0, -1):
   print(let[0].capitalize(), *let[1:i])
```

Comment: It works too but when I look at your solution I'm wondering what is going on here: 
let2 = [ i[1].capitalize() if i[0] == 0 else i[1] for i in enumerate(let) ]

what's i[1]?

Comment: I removed that example as it was probably too complicated (it's fairly generic python but looks scary if you are new at this).  It builds a copy of the list but capitalizes the first element.  The first part `i[1].capitalize() if i[0] == 0 else i[1]` is a tertiary statement that says if it's the first position `i[0] == 0` capitalize the value `i[1].capitalize()`, otherwise just return the original value.  The 2nd part, `for i in enumerate(let)` is a list comprehension and enumerate returns a 2-tuple per list entry (position, value).

Comment: haha I've a copy still looking at it and thinking: why capitalize i[1] when I want i[0] but it works as should lol

Comment: is it because enumerating does do 1,2,3,4 not like index 0,1,2,3,4?
I guess it's that.

Comment: No, enumerate starts with 0.  i[0] is the first element of the tuple which is the position, and i[1] is the value of the tuple which is what we get from the list.  (0, 'a'), (1, 'b') etc.